# 32536 bus error ./program, due to my use recv?

Tags: c

I have a "bus error" in the way I program. I am learning how to make a client /server with chained list. The error bus comes only when I return `parse_message (...) = NULL`..

The listen_client function is in a thread, I do not know if it affects the error. If you want more details / other piece of code ask me.

Thank you and good evening.

```
static t_message    *parse_message(char *buffer)
{
    int     id;

    id = atoi(buffer);
    printf("ID: %d\n", id);
    return (NULL); // for sample
}
static char     *read_message(char *data)
{
    static char     *buffer = NULL;
    char            *message = NULL;
    char            *ptr;
    size_t          size;

    size = strlen(data);
    if (buffer)
        size += strlen(buffer);
    if (!(buffer = realloc(buffer, size)))
        return (NULL);
    strcat(buffer, data);
    if ((ptr = strstr(buffer, "\r\n")))
    {
        size = (ptr - buffer);
        if (!(message = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1))))
            return (NULL);
        strncpy(message, buffer, size);
        ptr += 2;
        if (!(*ptr))
            buffer = NULL;
        else if (!(buffer = strdup(ptr)))
            return (NULL);
    }
    return (message);
}

void            listen_client(t_args *args)
{
    ssize_t     count;
    char        buffer[BUFF_SIZE + 1] = { 0 };
    char        *msg_str;
    t_message   *msg;

    while ((count = recv(args->client->s, buffer, BUFF_SIZE, 0)))
    {
        printf("===> %s\n", buffer);
        if (!(msg_str = read_message(buffer)))
        {
            continue ;
        }
        if (!(msg = parse_message(msg_str)))
        {   
            // bus error after continue ;
            continue ;
        }
        handle_message();
    }
```

Comment: I do not see the error in my code

Comment: `buffer` is not large enough (needs space for trainling `\0`) and its content is undefined (-> `strcat()` problem)